# Getting underlying Subsystem Inport/Outport Block via Port Handle

Tags: matlab, simulink

What is the best possible solution to get an underlying MATLAB Simulink Subsystem Inport/Outport Block via Port Handle?

I use the following code snippet for Outports to navigate from the Connection-Line to the Port Handle and determine the Parent/Port Number for searching it via `find_system`:

```
SrcPort = get_param(Line,'SrcportHandle'); 
SrcPortParent = get(SrcPort,'Parent');
SrcPortNumber = get(SrcPort,'PortNumber');
SrcPortBlock = find_system(SrcPortParent,'LookUnderMasks','all','FollowLinks','On','SearchDepth',1,'BlockType','Outport','Port',num2str(SrcPortNumber));
```

Is there a better solution to get the underlying Port Block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straightforward way, you already found what I consider the best option. For reference, [the MathWorks Support Team confirms that there is no better option.](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93314-how-can-i-find-the-names-of-the-ports-within-a-subsystem-that-an-external-block-is-connected-to-in-s)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the link. So I can assume that it is not because of my own inadequacy.